# Saving list from python to text file in format

Tags: python, file-io

Say I have a txt file,

```
fantasy,12/03/2014
sci-fi,13/04/2014
history,03/04/2014
```

And I use the following code to convert it into a python list

```
def load_list(filename):
    my_file = open(filename, "rU")
    my_list = []
    for line in my_file:
        a,b = line.rstrip("\n").split(",")
        my_list.append((as_datetime(b),a))
    my_file.close()
    return my_list
```

which outputs
     [(datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 12, 0, 0), 'fantasy'), (datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 3, 0,
     0), 'history'), (datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 12, 0, 0), 'sci-fi')].

I can assume that the list will be further modified (appended and removed) while being used. My question is, how can I implement a function to export the list as a txt file that followed the formatting of the original file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module for reading and writing.

In order to follow the date format, use `strptime()` and `strftime()` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)) from the `datetime` module.

Here's a complete example:

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime

FORMAT = '%d/%m/%Y'

def load_list(filename):
    my_list = []
    with open(filename, "rU") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for line in reader:
            my_list.append([line[0], datetime.strptime(line[1], FORMAT)])
    return my_list


def save_list(filename, my_list):
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        for item in my_list:
            writer.writerow([item[0], item[1].strftime(FORMAT)])


my_list = load_list('input.txt')
save_list('output.txt', my_list)
```

It reads the data from `input.txt` and writes it to `output.txt`. After running the script, `output.txt` contains the same data as `input.txt`:

```
fantasy,12/03/2014
sci-fi,13/04/2014
history,03/04/2014
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: One more question - instead of the `from datetime import datetime` that you are using, I have been given seperate functions to convert dates to and from datetime. the function that converts the string into datetime works fine `( my_list.append([as_datetime(line[1]), line[0]])`, but converting the datetime into a string in the save_list function is giving an error. The function for converting datetime to string is `def as_date_string(date):
    return date.strftime(DATE_FORMAT)` is not working when I call it like this `writer.writerow([item[0], as_date_string(item[1])])`

Comment: @Chrystael ok, what error are you getting? What is the value of a datetime at the point? What is `DATE_FORMAT`?

Comment: This is the entire error:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
    save_list("outputtest.txt", my_list)
  File "C:\Users\anon\Desktop\Python 1\assign1test.py", line 53, in save_list
    writer.writerow([item[0], as_date_string(item[1])])
  File "C:\Users\anon\Desktop\Python 1\assign1test.py", line 30, in as_date_string
    return date.strftime(DATE_FORMAT)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'`

DATE_FORMAT is simply FORMAT from your solution.

Comment: @Chrystael the error says that `date` is a string at the point, not datetime. Cannot say more without seeing the code you are using.

Comment: The difference being that instead of using `from datetime import datetime`, I am using `import datetime` and the seperate functions 
`def as_datetime(date_string):
    try:
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, DATE_FORMAT)`
and
`def as_date_string(date):
    return date.strftime(DATE_FORMAT)`
to change the date between a string and a datetime.

Comment: nevermind, I figured it out. It was because I changed the lines around in the load function, so it was calling the wrong item to be changed. Thanks for all your help!